# Show file name in textarea within a text

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an input type file and textarea. I want to show the file name in textarea on input type file change. Here I have reached something, but this works only for the first time and when I write some text and want to select another file I don't get that file name in textarea.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>victory please</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <style>
  #list {
   width: 500px;
   height: 650px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="file" name="img[]" id="file">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
 <br><br>
 <textarea id="list" name="list"></textarea>
 <div id="demo"></div>
 <script>
  $('#file').change(function () {
   var value = $('#file').val();
   $('#list').append(value);
  });
  $('#submit').click(function() {
   var a = getElementById('list').value;
   getElementById('demo') = a;
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you disable `textarea`?

Comment: @NimittShah because I need both to write text and show selected files' names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.value` or `.innerHtml` after write manually in textarea.

For example change this:

```
$('#list').append(value);
```

into:

```
$('#list').val($('#list').val()+value);
```

should works.

Comment: just type `$('#list').val();` for get value of textarea.in this case it may help you: `$("#demo").html($('#list').val());`